# displayed 'block' divs inside several 'inline' divs

Tags: css

My problem can be better understood by the image below.

I have several div elements (div A) which have a variable size that depends on their content.
They are displayed inblock inside a larger container with a max-with defined(the large outer rectangle without a name).
Everything works fine until I had inside divs A two other divs (B and C) which I what that look like the image.

I haven´t been successful. I've tried several combinations of css properties like display, margin, padding, float... negative margins... tables...

Any help would be welcome.

[image]

---

### Update

the code looks like the example:

**html**

```
 <div style="max-width: 800px;">
    <div class="div_a">
      <div class="div_b">
        short text
      </div>
      <div class="div_c">
        short text
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="div_a">
      <div class="div_b">
        looooong text
      </div>
      <div class="div_c">
        looooong text
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="div_a">
      <div class="div_b">
        huuuuuge text
      </div>
      <div class="div_c">
        huuuuuge text
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.div_a{
  display: inline;
}

.div_b{
  display: block; /* doesn't work*/
}

.div_c{
  display: block; /* doesn't work*/
}
```

Comment: @BoltClock, an update with the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this should do it:

```
.div_a{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

:)

...assuming you don't have other styles, besides border and spacing properties.

[A fiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/v6hLR/)

Comment: inline-block sometimes causes un-wanted margins. If that is the case, use float:left instead...